# My gold tag badge insta-close shouldn't apply if I just edited the relevant tag out of the question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, edits, dupehammer

The question [eclipse copy resource in C project after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924563/eclipse-copy-resource-in-c-project-after-build) was originally tagged [c] and I found it via the C close queue.  I have a gold tag badge for C.

My assessment of the question was

- It doesn't actually have anything to do with C; it's a "how do I do a specific thing in my Eclipse project (that happens to have C in it)" question.
- It is *plausibly* a duplicate of the question someone linked as a possible duplicate.  However, I don't personally know much of anything about Eclipse and maybe there's a reason that technique doesn't apply here.

So what I did was I edited the [c] tag out, and *then* voted to close as a duplicate, expecting to provide just a regular close vote.  Instead, the magic insta-close hammer fired.  I think this is a bug.

Comment: This is by design actually (for now). Only tags that were present in the original revision of the question are taken into account, *even if they have been subsequently removed*. So, `[feature-request]` may be a better tag for this question.

Comment: The dupe hammer works on the **initial** tags on the question - which is to prevent you adding a tag where you do have a gold badge and instantly closing - however, I can't see why it shouldn't notice if the tag was *removed*.

Comment: @ChrisF Some gold badge users have requested the ability to be able to put a close vote that would not close instantly (when they are not sure I guess). As I recall, this possibility was *explicitly* refused. What I understand you suggesting here would give them the opportunity to turn their vote into a normal one, no?

Comment: @Louis I get it: remove tag, vote at normal weight, restore tag! (Step 4 - profit!)

Comment: @ChrisF: Maybe it should work according to the tags of the last edition not authored by the voter instead. That might be less surprising and more useful.

Comment: @Louis - yes it would - which is an argument against the change.

Comment: @Deduplicator - That's an interesting idea, but wouldn't help in this case where the person removing the tag was the person voting to close.

Comment: @Deduplicator I would find that *more* surprising.  (I don't get the arguments against, honestly.  Why would it be bad for me to have the ability to put the big hammer down if I think that's appropriate?)

Comment: @Zack The argument mostly is that then, people will do exactly that, defeating the purpose of the feature somewhat, and also if you aren't 100% dead certain something absolutely should be closed, you shouldn't be voting to close anyway.

Comment: You should **always** be *sure* about your close votes. Don't vote to close anything unless you are certain about the dupe. That goes for any posts, not just where you have a dupe hammer.

Comment: I just ran into this problem with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449846/apportioning-data-into-new-columns The OP mistakenly tagged it as mysql when it's actually sql-server. I changed the tag, and was surprised when my dupehammer took effect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't particularly like the idea of "the last edit not by the closer".  That allows either two users working together to cast the vote of 5, or a trivial edit that didn't influence tags to make the tag part of the trigger set.

At the same time, triggering on removed tags seems wrong.

Therefore I suggest:

- Apply the hammer if intersection of (gold tag badges held by close voter, tags in initial revision of question, tags in current revision of question) is non-empty.